# Cannot open sockets after suspend

Tags: networking, suspend, connection, resume, sockets

When I boot my computer everything works fine, but after resuming from suspend applications are not able to open new local sockets. My connection and DNS are fine. I can ping domains. I can browse websites, I can SSH out, I can connect to services started before resuming. But I cannot start anything that wants to bind to a new local socket. If I reboot everything will work again, but I have to force reboot because stopping Tomcat stalls waiting for network.

adb:

```
adb F 05-03 15:31:03 54241 54241 main.cpp:148] could not install *smartsocket* listener: Address family not supported by protocol

* failed to start daemon
adb: failed to check server version: cannot connect to daemon
```

Tomcat:

```
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address (Bind failed)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:428)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:800)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:746)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:284)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:415)
```

netcat:

```
$ nc -vkl 12345
Listening on 0.0.0.0 12345

$ telnet localhost 12345
Trying 127.0.0.1...
```

I have tried restarting network-manager, systemd-udevd, systemd-sysctl and docker. All to no avail. I've also compared `ip link|route|addr` before and after resume and they are identical.

I'm at a complete loss as to what the problem could be. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this. I have haproxy and dnsmasq running in Docker, so I need to assign a second ip to the loopback interface and add a nameserver. I had done this using netplan as such:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    lo:
      renderer: networkd
      addresses:
        - 10.10.10.10/8
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 10.10.10.10
```

Everything works correctly on startup, but after resuming lo only has the IP 10.10.10.10, not 127.0.0.1.

To fix this I added the normal ip's to the netplan and everything works as expected now.

```
network:
  ethernets:
    lo:
      renderer: networkd
      match:
        name: lo
      addresses:
        - 127.0.0.1/8
        - ::1/128
        - 10.10.10.10/32
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 10.10.10.10
```

I don't know if this is the most idiomatic way to do this in Ubuntu, but it is working for me.